# Can I use essential oils instead of athlete's foot cream?

Tags: health

Many essential oils are anti fungal, and have been shown to inhibit or kill athlete's foot.

ie. https://ndnr.com/bacterialviral-infections/exploring-essential-oils-in-the-treatment-of-tinea-pedis/

I've tried various oils like lavender, tea tree, Vick's Vapor Rub mixture and all they did was make my skin itchier. Disappointing results.

Is there a good, proven way to kill foot fungus with essential oils ?

Comment: Thanks for the question! Although I don't have an answer for you, I do have a lot of experience with this Lifehacks community website. You can probably get a broader range of answers with a question like, "Other than athlete's foot cream, what are some ways to treat athlete's foot? I'd like to use essential oils, but the ones I've tried only made my skin itchier. Any other suggestions?" This question _might_ be good on the StackExchange site for medicine, but they don't like questions about the person's specific condition, only about medical conditions in an abstract sense.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but some compounds that you should investigate are: gentian violet, iodophor, potassium permanganate. These are older compounds that have an anti-microbial effect. I'm not positive they work on athlete's foot (though gentian violet does). Some essential oils have harmful effects, so be careful with them. They are from inside plants, but so is turpentine.

Comment: Oh! I specifically read something about this, and iodine tincture it more likely to be helpful than iodophor. First, because I read a patent about it (though not a guarantee it works), and second, a study that said iodophor allows twice as many blood culture infections as iodine tincture when used before drawing blood. It must be because iodophor is stabilized to limit the amount of elemental iodine, while iodine tincture will become more concentrated as it dries.

Answer (score 1):

What I used was anti dandruff shampoo. Rub it on and wait a minute then rinse it off.
Be sure to alternate shoes every other day. As well ,change your socks after you take off the footwear that you were sweating in.
Added bonus tip, if your baby has diaper rash, add a spoonful to their bath water. Just don't get the bath water in their eyes.

Comment: Nice idea. I found a thread here with a few suggestions
https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/1at4ql/lpt_dandruff_shampoo_can_be_used_to_fight/

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the possibility that your itching is caused by dry skin. The oil and chemicals may be have already killed the foot fungus but are leaving your feet dry and itchy. By far the best thing I have found is Gold Bond extra strength body lotion. It comes in a green plastic bottle. It both moisturizes and relieves the itchy skin.

Comment: Oh yeah there's no doubt the raw essential oil I put on irritated the skin a lot. I tried lavender and tea tree. Also the Vick's vapor rub, that's not so bad.
Which, BTW has been studied here
https://www.nursesinaidscarejournal.org/article/S1055-3290(15)00240-X/fulltext